# Java Applet will not load

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt

I've been trying to get this java applet to work on my website for the past few hours. I keep getting this error when I try to run the applet on my webhost.
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

I do not understand why. I'm using GoDaddy for webhosting. Here's the class the html is supposed to run:

```
package render;

import java.awt.*; 
import java.util.ArrayList;

import scenes.Scene;

import entities.Entity;
import entities.Sprite;
import entities.object.*;
import entities.things.*;

public class Render extends Game{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static Image offScreenImage;
    public static Graphics offScreenGraphics;

    public static Dimension window_size = new Dimension(1200,750);


    public void init(){
        this.setPreferredSize(window_size);
        this.setSize(this.getPreferredSize());


        offScreenImage = createImage(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight()); // creates an image of window size
        offScreenGraphics = offScreenImage.getGraphics();   
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        offScreenGraphics.clearRect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());

        ArrayList<Scene> sro = new ArrayList<Scene>();
        sro.addAll(0, Game.getOverlayScenes()); //sro = scene render order
        sro.add(sro.size(),Game.getScene());

        for (int j=sro.size()-1;j>-1;--j){ // To render scenes in a stack, overlays being over the main scene.

            for (EntityObject i:sro.get(j).objects()){

                    if (i.getVisibility()){

                    if (i.getDrawingType() == Entity.draw_types[0]){
                        Sprite sprite = ((ImageEntity)i).getSprite();
                        try{
                            offScreenGraphics.drawImage(sprite.getImageReference(),(int)sprite.getPosition().getX(),(int)sprite.getPosition().getY(),this);
                        }catch(NullPointerException e){}
                    }else if (i.getDrawingType() == Entity.draw_types[1]){
                        //TODO - Add in text objects
                        //offScreenGraphics.drawString(, x, y);
                    }else if (i.getDrawingType().equals(Entity.draw_types[2])){
                        offScreenGraphics.fillRect((int)i.getPosition().getX(),(int)i.getPosition().getY(),
                                ((Box)i).getRectX(),((Box)i).getRectY());
                    }
                }


            }
        }

        // draws graphics to screen
        g.drawImage(offScreenImage,0,0,this);
     }

    public void update(Graphics g){
        paint(g);
    }
}
```

And the Game class

```
package render;

import global.Global;
import input.KeyboardInput;
import input.MouseInput;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.Timer;

import resources.ImageLibrary;
import resources.SceneLibrary;
import scenes.Scene;
import scenes.SceneBuilder;
import scenes.more.*;


public class Game extends Applet implements ActionListener{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static Timer timer;
    private static int fps = Global.getFPS();

    private static KeyboardInput keyboard = new KeyboardInput();
    private static MouseInput mouse = new MouseInput();

    private static Scene current_scene = new SuperScene();
    private static ArrayList<Scene> overlay_scenes = new ArrayList<Scene>();


    public Game(){
        timer = new Timer(1000/fps,this); // makes timer object that runs 30 times a second
        timer.start();

        ImageLibrary.setupHashMaps();
        SceneLibrary.setupHashMaps();

        SceneBuilder.buildScene(new StartMenu());

        // Keyboard setup
        this.addKeyListener(keyboard); // Window needs to grab the KeyEvents
        // Mouse setup
        this.addMouseListener(mouse);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(mouse);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        EntityUpdater.updateObjects();

        keyboard.poll();
        mouse.poll();

        //repaint - redraws everything
        repaint();

    }

    public static void setScene(Scene scene){
        current_scene = scene;
    }

    public static Scene getScene(){
        return current_scene;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Scene> getOverlayScenes(){
        return overlay_scenes;
    }

    public static void addOverlayScene(Scene scene){
        overlay_scenes.add(scene);
    }

    public static void removeOverlayScene(Scene scene){
        overlay_scenes.remove(scene);
    }


    public static KeyboardInput getKeyboard(){
        return keyboard;
    }

    public static MouseInput getMouse(){
        return mouse;
    }


}
```

Here's the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<applet code = "render.Render.class" archive = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9279065/Babi.jar" width = 1280 height = 720></applet>

</body>
</html>
```

You may notice that in the html code, I have provided a link to my .jar.

Could I be exporting this wrong?

Any ideas?

Oh and that is the only error I got. I would post everything, but when I click "details" nothing comes up.

Comment: Can you post the `Game` class?

Comment: Can you post the full exception...

Comment: I posted the Game class and I can't post the full exception (read post).

Comment: Raise the output level of the Java Console to 5 & you might see `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at resources.ImageLibrary.<clinit>(ImageLibrary.java:17)
 ... 28 more`

Answer (score 0):

Unsigned applets will not load code from an archive located on another host address due to the security restrictions imposed by the security sandbox. This causes an `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

Either move the applet JAR file to the applet web host address (GoDaddy) or sign the applet.

Applet after moving the JAR file to same host:

```
<applet code = "render.Render.class" archive = "Babi.jar" width = 1280 height = 720></applet>
```

Comment: So I added the JAR into the applet web host... Still  get the same error. :/

Comment: Did you remove HTTPS as the protocol for the archive in the applet tag? Also ensure that you are showing the maximum possible output debug information in the console window (by pressing `5`) as indicated in the comments above